# Why did "the human race became a small committee surrounded by affectionate animals" for Sartre in the Words?

Tags: meaning, french-language, jean-paul-sartre

What is Sartre's metaphor meaning in *the Words* when saying :

> *"The  human race  became  a  small  committee  surrounded  by affectionate  animals."*

The context is when he begins to become familiar with all the writers of his grandfather's library. He tells us about his child perception of their duties : they had to write masterpieces as far as they were writers. Why should anyone praise them as far as they are only doing their duties, he asks as a child. As a narrator, now an adult, he acknowledges he got it all wrong about them. Are the small comitee the writers and the commoners the affectionate animals ?

He uses lots of references in this part of the book. He also talks about Charles V

> *when  I  was  told  that  Charles  V  had  picked  up Titian's  brush,  I  was  not  at  all surprised. What of  it ?  That  was  what  princes  were  made  for.*

Which I don't get neither ...